# Only include specific cookies in Fetch request

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch-api

We're trying to use the JavaScript Fetch API to make requests to the server. While normally we are fine with sending cookies (using the `credentials: 'include'` option), in this particular use case we want to hit the same API endpoint while not sending *all* our cookies, but rather just a select *few* cookies.
Our use case is to allow us to behave anonymously to the API based on our URL parameters on our site. For example, if we go to our site at `https://SomeRadSite.com` (no idea if that's an actual site, don't go there to find out) we want our cookies to be sent to validate we're logged in and behave as such. But if we go to our site at `https://SomeRadSite.com?isAnonymous=true`, then we don't want to send all our cookies (only a few) so that any interactions and API calls that take place will all be anonymous.

Again, to summarize the question. Can I selectively choose which cookies (**not** an all or nothing approach) to send when making a Fetch request?

Whether or not the example posted is best practice isn't really the question (that particular code is out of my hands). I'm ultimately trying to discover if I can selectively choose which cookies can be submitted with a fetch request.

Comment: A cookie is the wrong tool for the use case you describe. Query parameters or POST request body are the _user defined_ ways of dynamically modifying requests to servers. You can certainly abuse the wrong tool if you'd like and get it to work for you (after adding a few hundred lines of additional code).

Comment: Alternatively, opening my mind a bit, you could use a second end point `SomeRadSite/anonymous`, rather than a query parameter. Then tune the cookies so they only apply to the base URL. That way no cookies would apply to the subURL.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, we had a second endpoint for a while, but it had to be a duplicate, which caused other issues elsewhere. In the end, whether or not this is the best approach to achieve the desired result isn't up to me. I'm simply trying to find out if it's possible to selectively post cookies with fetch requests.